# JSON Schema Validation With typecasting feature

Tags: java, json, node.js

Please suggest how to perform typecasting before validation of JSON Schema in Java. I've achieved the same in NodeJS using **json-schema-validation-pipeline** package. Below code snippet for reference (where param1 was actually of type string as provided from backend API).

```
var ValidationPipeline = require('json-schema-validation-pipeline');
var V = ValidationPipeline.V;
    var validate = ValidationPipeline([
        {
            $schema: {
                'param1': V(Number).min(60)
            }
        },
        { $cast: { param1: Number } }
    ]);
```

So basically, I am looking for equivalent solution in Java for above code snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to POJO model class of JAVA and once you have this native object then you can typecast to anything as its in language operation For example-

```
File file = new File("json/student.json");  

   // get json as buffer  
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  

   // obtained Gson object  
   Gson gson = new Gson();  //import com.google.gson.Gson;  

   // called fromJson() method and passed incoming buffer from json file  
   // passed student class reference to convert converted result as Student object  
   Student student = gson.fromJson(br, Student.class);
```